# I can't upload image due to "Call to a member function X on a non-object" in PHP

Tags: codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Ncatering::$upload
>
> Filename: controllers/Ncatering.php
>
> Line Number: 134
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\National\admin\application\controllers\Ncatering.php
>   Line: 134
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\National\admin\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\National\admin\application\controllers\Ncatering.php on line 134
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Ncatering.php
>
> Line Number: 134
>
> Backtrace:

This is my controller:

```
 function add_gallery()
{
    //$this->load->model('Mcatering');
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|mp3';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'); 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $img = $this->upload->data();
        $imgname = $img['file_name'];
        $sss=$this->input->post('sss');
        $data=array('image'=>$imgname,'sss'=>$sss);
        //$data=array('sss'=>$sss);
        $this->Mcatering->insertgallery($data);
               redirect('Ncatering/gallery');
```

This is my form for upload image:

```
          <?php echo form_open_multipart('Ncatering/add_gallery/'); ?>
               <div class="box-body">
               <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Image</label>
              <input type="file" name="userfile" accept="image/jpeg" 
       width="900" height="600" id="exampleInputFile">
            </div>
             </div>
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color:#FC0;">Submit</button>
          </div>
       <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Show us where line 134 is

Comment: thats very strange - it looks like the line `$this->load->library('upload',$config);` doesnt load the library at all.. check in your config.php `$config['log_threshold']` and turn the value to `2` if it isn't already - after that take a look @your `application/logs` folder and open the log for that day - and take a closer look, maybe you find some hints...

Comment: line number 134          $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');   -Mr.ED

Comment: Thanks everyone.Bt my problem is not solved,

Comment: change `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');` with `$this->upload->do_upload();`

Comment: Have you loaded the upload library any where else like on config/autoload.php or some where else on controller because I have came across once if I loaded twice will through error.

Comment: Or try it in a if statement like it explains here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. you can try core php function `move_uploaded_file()` for uploading your file

```
                    $target_dir = "upload/";
                    $imgName1 = time().basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
                    $imgName= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $imgName1);
                    $target_file = $target_dir . $imgName;
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Your file name will be stored in variable `$imgName`

Comment: I used these code for uploading images in 3 websites. Bt problem is only for this work .I don'nt know why it is.

Answer (score -1):

It works fine for me...The following function is helpful to image upload...

**In view file**

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'event_form');
    echo form_open_multipart('events/create', $attributes); 
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Upload Images</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="events_file" id="gallery-photo-add">
                <?php echo form_error('events_file', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

<?php form_close(); ?>
```

**In Controller**

```
<?php
public function create()
{
    $web = array();
    $web['title'] = 'Events List create';
    $web['content'] = 'web/events';
    $web['isNewRecord'] = 1;

     if (empty($_FILES['events_file']['name'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('events_file', 'Images', 'required');             
     }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('web_template',$web);
    } else {

        $files = $_FILES;

        $count = count($_FILES['events_file']['name']);

        $_FILES['events_file']['name']= time().'_'.$files['events_file']['name'];
        $_FILES['events_file']['type']= $files['events_file']['type'];
        $_FILES['events_file']['tmp_name']= $files['events_file']['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['events_file']['error']= $files['events_file']['error'];
        $_FILES['events_file']['size']= $files['events_file']['size'];

        $uploadPath = 'uploads/events/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('events_file')){
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadData['event_id'] = $insert_id;
            $uploadData['image'] = $fileData['file_name'];

        }

        if(!empty($uploadData)){
            $this->db->insert('events_image',$uploadData);   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't think you can help op, by posting some random code snippet... Did you even read his question ?